# Using ng-repeat with table rows

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to insert data from a model into a template but I want to add a new table row after every 7 repetitions. With strign-based templates I could do it quite easily using the iteration index and modulo but I can't quite figure out how to do this using angular's DOM templates.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <colgroup span="7"></colgroup>

   <tbody>
     <tr class="days">
       <th scope="col" title="Monday">Mon</th>
       <th scope="col" title="Tuesday">Tue</th>
       <th scope="col" title="Wednesday">Wed</th>
       <th scope="col" title="Thursday">Thu</th>
       <th scope="col" title="Friday">Fri</th>
       <th scope="col" title="Saturday">Sat</th>
       <th scope="col" title="Sunday">Sun</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td ng-repeat="date in dates">
             {{ date }}
             <!-- After seven iterations a new `<tr>` should be aded -->
        </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

And the javascript it something like:

```
myApp = this.angular.module('myApp', []);

var monthDays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 1516, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31];

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  return $scope.dates = monthDays;
});​
```

You can view the code in a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3zhbB/2/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make `$scope.dates` an array of arrays with the days.

Each array inside of it is a row, and each day inside of the row's array is a day

See this updated JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6aqtj/1/

Comment: Thanks,I was hoping that there might be a way to do it inside the template without altering the array in the controller. It doesn't look like this is possible at the moment however.

Comment: I created a filter that is re-usable based on this answer: http://jsfiddle.net/interlock/qhewP/2/

Answer (score 9):

If you'd like to leave your scope data the way it is (as an array), you could write a directive, and encapsulate all of the HTML generation there, hence:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <calendar></calendar>
</div>

myApp.directive('calendar', function() {
// Requires that scope contains a 'monthDays' array.
// Adds 'weeks' to scope.
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">'
    + ...
    + '<th scope="col" title="Sunday">Sun</th></tr>'
    + '<tr ng-repeat="week in weeks">'
    + '<td ng-repeat="day in week">{{day}}</td>'
    + '</tr></tbody></table>',
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.weeks = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.monthDays.length; i++) {
            if (i % 7 == 0) {
                scope.weeks.push([]);
            }
            scope.weeks[scope.weeks.length-1].push(scope.monthDays[i]);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/dGpsr/

Answer (score 5):

You can do this pretty easily with your current data.  I just added a simple filter: http://jsfiddle.net/3zhbB/6/

It's not really the best solution though, as it's pretty inefficient.  It will have to create a new array and do a lot of slicing.  But it's still cool :-D

Comment: I liked this solution very much. It is a pity that the SO post is so brief when the jsfiddle it points to is so elegant. With underscore.js, however, it gets even better: `myApp.filter('array', function() { return _.range; });`

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Renan about the array of arrays and got caught up in an attempt to make this more calendar-like. Assuming you want blank table cells and you want the month to start on the correct day of the week (0-6). Have a look at this function:

```
function generateWeeks(startDay, numDays){
  var weeks = [];
  var numWeeks = (numDays + startDay) / 7;
  for(var i=0; i<numWeeks; i++){
    weeks[i] = [];
    for(var j=0; j<7; j++){
      if(i==0 && j<startDay){
        weeks[i].push('');
      }else{
        var day = (j-startDay+1)+(i*7);
        weeks[i].push(day<=numDays ? day : '');
      }
    }
  }
  return weeks;
}
```

For the current month, I'd call generateWeeks(5,30). September has 30 days and started on Saturday (and your calendar week is Monday - Sunday).

```
<tr ng-repeat="week in weeks">
  <td ng-repeat="day in week">{{day}}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem myself. Instead of html tables though, I'm going to use an unordered list over a single "days" collection and use css to make it look like a table. So, if each element is 14% wide, it will wrap on 7 automatically.

This was the genesis of my approach:
[Creating three-column table with CSS only? (No table element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474737/creating-three-column-table-with-css-only-no-table-element)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional like `$index % 7 == 0` to write the `</tr><tr>`

I just created a simple table like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .selectable.year {
        display:inline-block; 
        width:25%;
        border-right-width:0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .selectable.year.first {
        margin-left:0;
    }
    .selectable.year.lastcol, .selectable.year:last-child {
        border-right-width:1px;
    }
</style>
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="selectable year" 
        ng-class="{ 'firstcol' : $index % 4 == 0 , 'lastcol' : $index % 4 == 3 }"
        ng-repeat="year in search.yearList"
        <span class="caption">{{ year }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see, it wraps .. its not a table, really.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question that nevertheless now has a clean answer! The whole process of repeating complex sections in angular is vastly improved by the use of the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`, which you can read about in detail here:

http://www.undefinednull.com/2015/04/10/repeating-multiple-elements-using-ng-repeat-start-and-ng-repeat-end-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

For angular 5+ use ngFor instead of ng-repeat.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let mi of mileages; let i = index">
                            <td>{{mi.fromAddress}}</td>
</tr>
```