# applying filter to ng-repeat to produce a fixed-column table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

There are many examples of filters applied to ng-repeats. All these examples assume that the ng-repeat will produce a single list. There are [a few examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518259/using-ng-repeat-with-table-rows) of how to put a list of items in a table such that each cell contains one item and the table has a fixed number of columns.

How does one combine these?

Answer (score 0):

First, an app and a controller that contain the items and the number of table columns:

```
var app = angular.module("GridApp", []);
app.controller("GridCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["John", "Jesus", "Bob", "Sandy", "Jonah",
                    "Fry", "Jenny", "Helmuth", "Janus", "Ben" ];
    $scope.ncol = 3;
});
```

Second, a helper function that turns the angular expression `n` into `[0, 1, ..., n-1]`:

```
app.filter('array', function() {
    return function(arrayLength) {
        arrayLength = Math.ceil(arrayLength);
        var arr = new Array(arrayLength);
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
        return arr;
    };
});
```

Third and finally, two nested `ng-repeat`s over the filtered set of items:

```
<div>
  <h2>Search</h2>
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
</div>

<div>
  <h2>Items</h2>
  <button ng-click="ncol = ncol + 1">+</button>
  <button ng-click="ncol = ncol - 1">-</button>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="column in ((items | filter:searchText).length/ncol | array)">
      <td ng-repeat="item in (items | filter:searchText).slice(ncol*$index, ncol*$index+ncol)">
        {{item}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```